# JWT jti uniqueness

Tags: jwt

I'm having some trouble understanding how I'm supposed to use the `jti` claim in JWT. As far as I can see in other SO questions and from docs online, the idea is they should be unique, but unique to what scope? A jti per site/app? A jti per token/user? And if I have a jti specific to the user, doesn't that sort of undo the point of a JWT being stateless, as I'd need to somehow track the token?

I'd love to get some help understanding how to use the jti, or if maybe I don't need it at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`jti` should be unique in the **scope of the application** in order to prevent  two equal JWT.

See [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7)

> **4.1.7.  "jti" (JWT ID) Claim**

> The "jti" (JWT ID) claim provides a unique identifier for the JWT.
> The identifier value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that
> there is a negligible probability that the same value will be
> accidentally assigned to a different data object; if the application
> uses multiple issuers, collisions MUST be prevented among values
> produced by different issuers as well.  The "jti" claim can be used
> to prevent the JWT from being replayed.  The "jti" value is a case-
> sensitive string.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

It could be useful if you need a blacklist to revoke tokens and to ensure the same same JWT is not issued twice (when contains the same content without timestamp claims)

Comment: I think the "same JWT is not issued twice" is what's been throwing me off. Within the same app, the same user would be getting the same token, barring timestamp changes (I'm also not sure how often to reissue a token; on every page load seems excessive), but that's an entirely different question.

Comment: the idea is if a user were to keep that token, it can't be replayed once they tried to refresh it. It's pretty much a safeguard against replay attacks.